# aws s3 upload fail only at production envrionment, but success at local environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I tried to upload image using aws-sdk, multer-s3.
In my local environment, uploading image was succeed, but in production environment(aws lambda), it fail with error status 403 forbidden.
But my aws credential key and secret-key is same as local environment. also i checked aws key in production environment successfully.

I think difference between two other environment is nothing.What am I missing?

I have even tried setting aws key in my router code like below, but it also failed.

```
AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'blabla';
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'blalbla';
AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-2';
```

and here is my policy

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1536755128154",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1536755126539",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elebooks-image/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you get an error on accessing the lambda itself?

Comment: Ohter lambda fuction like login, writing post is works..!

Comment: Is your lambda is a VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Update your attached s3 bucket policy to a user according to below policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

it's working on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with AWS Lambda but I am familiar with S3. When you're using the AWS SDK in your local environment, you're probably using the root user with default full access, so it will just work.

With Lambda however, according to the following extract from the documentation, you need to make sure that the IAM role you specified when you created the Lambda function has the appropriate permissions to do an s3:putObject to that bucket.

> Permissions for your Lambda function – Regardless of what invokes a Lambda function, AWS Lambda executes the function by assuming the IAM role (execution role) that you specify at the time you create the Lambda function. Using the permissions policy associated with this role, you grant your Lambda function the permissions that it needs. For example, if your Lambda function needs to read an object, you grant permissions for the relevant Amazon S3 actions in the permissions policy. For more information, see Manage Permissions: Using an IAM Role (Execution Role).

See [Writing IAM policies: How to grant access to an S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Comment: I changed s3 policy (i updated question!) and IAM role is full access. but it didn't works....

Comment: I'm using same IAM in local environment and production environment. so both IAM policy are full access.

Comment: The owner of the account owns all the resources, so it wouldn't make sense to give it access via an IAM policy. IAM roles are used to restrict access for other users. Are you saying that the AWS credentials you are using locally are for "someOther" user, which is assigned the same IAM role as your Lambda function?